# Can I use Selenium Webdriver and Java for testing a Calculator Widget done in PHP?

Tags: java, php, performance, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium Webriver is not recognizing the elements in the Widget calculator. What could be wrong? The error "Element not found" is displaying. This is in Java. The Widget is PHP. Also, do I need to change all my scripts to using C# if the website is converted to .net?

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body div#guaranteedRatePartnerExchangeMortgagePaymentCalculatorContainer   div.calculatorForm div.row div.spanRight input.dollar")).clear();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Is the site you are trying to automate publicly visible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes.

You need to put ONLY the css selector you want, not all the stuff ....

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("text-align").
```

Or use By.tagSelector("html") :

```
driver.findElements(By.tags("div"). ..
```

Xavier

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: findElement execution failed;
 The window could not be found (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Now i see this message..so part of it is I change from driver.get("this website") to driver.get("the Widtest site link) is that the issue? Is it viewing the widget as a window